How to use SDKMAN Candidates like Maven or Gradle in linux [Kubuntu 24.04] terminal
How to use SDKMAN Candidates that come along with SDKMAN installation. Can it be used in the Linux Desktop for general build or on global scope like environment variables are created for the SDKMAN candidates like that Gradle, Groovy & Maven that come along with SDKMAN. Do we need any configuration steps neede for enabling the SDKMAN Candidates on the Linux VM. How can we use the SDKMAN Candidates like any other linux distro or command package. Kindly share pointers or URLs for reference of usage of SDKMAN Candidates in it's installed vm. I am interested more on the SDKMAN Candidates usage as most of them are Open-Source Tools.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I was unable to have multiversion of the Java JDK using SDKMAN as well with Gradle. My Installation steps were wrong, I chose one path in /usr/local/sdkman to hold the Candidates .sdkman libraries. Once reinstalling SDKMAN without any Tweaks I was able to choose Candidates version like Gradle & Maven. Thanks for hosting the query. Kindly close the query.
